# Use yarn workspaces and typescript's project references to reference another package subdirectory

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I use yarn workspaces and have the following packages:

- packages/x-cli
- packages/x-core

I want to be able to import symbols from x-core subdirectories, the same way you would do `import map from 'lodash/map'`, example:

```
import { fn } from '@mycompany/x-core/test';
```

But I get the following error:

```
tsc -b packages/x-core packages/x-cli
packages/x-cli/src/main.ts:1:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@mycompany/x-core/test'.

1 import { fn } from "@mycompany/x-core/test";
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This works though, if it is exported in the root of the library:

```
import { otherFn } from '@mycompany/x-core';
```

I made a small project on Github to show exactly my setup, based on lerna-yarn-workspaces-example: https://github.com/julienfouilhe/example-subdirectory-workspace-typescript-import

Is there a way to do this, I can't find anything that works. I don't know much about module resolution so I can't pinpoint the problem exactly!

Comment: Hi, any updates on this?

Comment: @chibis0v It seems that in order to do so I would have to move files around after compiling. If this is too troublesome for you (it is for me), you can either use `@mycompany/x-core/lib/test` or always export everything at the root of your library: `@mycompany/x-core`

Comment: do you have working go to definition function in vs code when importing like @mycompany/x-core?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to generate sourcemaps for that to map to the source files instead of the compiled files

Comment: Thank you! I resolved issue with go to definition through main property in package.json, but wait a minute.. did you just say we can generate sourcemaps and see then initial jsx code in chrome? :) Ho can we achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on this: With Nodejs 14, you can specify subpath exports in your package.json.

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_subpath_exports

I haven't tested that personally, but it looks like it can fix this issue by using

```
"exports": {
  ".": "./lib"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving to the root at builds works and avoids tooling issues but as mentioned it complicates building, especially for sharing in workspaces. The ["exports" field node 14](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_entry_points) is an important change that should ultimately make supporting subdirectory exports easier but for now it only solves part of the problem since other tooling doesn't seem to respect the field yet. The specific error mentioned would still exist with typescript's path resolution that can be resolved using the `"baseUrl"` and `"paths"` options in your `tsconfig.json` file at the root and then using `"extends"` to [share that config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515778/how-to-set-up-lerna-monorepo-with-typescript). Unfortunately if the lib ends up getting used by something built with webpack and you're using v4 you'll need to configure custom path resolution step because webpack doesn't [support the "exports"](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9509) field. It does appear to be part of webpack 5 if you can use that. So, if you're not publishing your lib outside of the mono repo then this is solvable without moving everything to the root with newer tools and some configuration work.