# How to set up Lerna monorepo with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, npm, package.json, monorepo

I have a `core` library with the following in `package.json`:

```
"main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
"module": "dist/esm/index.js",
"es2015": "dist/es2015/index.js",
"types": "dist/es2015/index.d.ts",
"typings": "dist/es2015/index.d.ts",
```

The library builds TypeScript code into `dist/` folder for distribution. The source code lies within `src/`.

I am using Lerna and monorepos, and I'm trying to get another package/module to load the TypeScript code as-is:

```
import { someTypeScriptStuff } from '@test/core'
```

However, this does not work. Both IntelliJ and TSLint complain about a missing module. If I change the value of the `main` field in `package.json` to `src/index.ts`, then it works.

**I don't want to compile the TS code into `dist` all the time in development, because it's painful.**

Obviously, I can't change the main field to `src/index.ts` either, because it's supposed to reference ordinary JavaScript that works as-is in node/browsers.

Is there a TypeScript specific field that I could use in `package.json` that both IntelliJ and TSLint could use instead? **That would be ideal.**

The only solution I can think of is to literally make the `main` field point to TS code and change my build process to mutate the contents of the packed NPM module by swapping the `main` field back to `dist/cjs/index.js` for distribution. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved it with this in the root `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./packages",
    "paths": {
      "@test/*": ["./*/src"]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And then I added this to every package's own `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src"
  }
}
```